# Javascript wrap element and insert at same position

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```js
this.newWrap = document.createElement("div");
this.newWrap.classList.add('xxx');

this.newWrap.appendChild(
    document.querySelector('.two')
);

document.querySelector('.wrap').insertBefore(
    this.newWrap,
    document.querySelector('.three')
);
```

```css
.xxx {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to insert the `this.newWrap` at the same position the element it wraps is. So to say with the same selector I use to wrap the element in this case `document.querySelector('.two')` and not `document.querySelector('.three')` like seen in the `.insertBefore()`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I would like to insert the `this.newWrap` with the same selector I use to wrap the element...

If you mean the same *parent*, and in the same place in that parent's child list, you do indeed use `insertBefore` — before moving the element you're wrapping:

```js
this.newWrap = document.createElement("div");
this.newWrap.classList.add('xxx');
var toWrap = document.querySelector('.two');
toWrap.parentNode.insertBefore(this.newWrap, toWrap);
this.newWrap.appendChild(toWrap);
```

```css
.xxx {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```

If you prefer to move the element first, though, that is also an option — you just keep track of its former parent and following sibling:

```js
this.newWrap = document.createElement("div");
this.newWrap.classList.add('xxx');
var toWrap = document.querySelector('.two');
var parent = toWrap.parentNode;
var next = toWrap.nextSibling;
this.newWrap.appendChild(toWrap);
parent.insertBefore(this.newWrap, next);
```

```css
.xxx {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```

That works even on the last element in its parent, because in that case `nextSibling` will be `null`, and if you pass `null` as the "before" element to `insertBefore`, it appends to the end. :-)

Comment: Indeed so simple (facepalm). Thank you, as always, much appreciated!